# getting error unknown group operator '$group' in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to count `distinct(not unique)` or `Emp No` in same `department`.but getting error

**query failed: unknown group operator '$group'**

here is my code
https://mongoplayground.net/p/UvYF9NB7vZx

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Department",
      total: {
        "$group": {
          _id: "$Emp No"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Expected output

```
[
  {
    "_id": "HUAWEI”,
“total”:1
  },
  {
    "_id": "THBS”,
“total”:2
  }
]
```

`THBS`have two different `Emp No`  `A10088P2C` and `A20088P2C`

`HUAWEI` have only one `Emp No` `A1016OBW`

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to count. There is no `$group` accumulator. Available accumulators are documented on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so, [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-aggregation) is Pipeline stage, you can only use it in upper level.

But for your required output there is lots of ways i believe, 
we can do something like this as well:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        dept: "$Department",
        emp: "$Emp No"
      },
      total: {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.dept",
      total: {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here, in first stage we are grouping with `Department` and its `Emp No` , and also we are having count of how many `Emp No` is in each dept. 
[this count you can remove though as we are not using it.]

result of this stage will be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "dept": "THBS",
      "emp": "A10088P2C"
    },
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "dept": "THBS",
      "emp": "A20088P2C"
    },
    "total": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "dept": "HUAWEI",
      "emp": "A1016OBW"
    },
    "total": 3
  }
]
```

next on top of this part data, i'm grouping again, with the dept. which comes in `$_id.dept`, and making count in the same way, which gives the result in your required format.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "HUAWEI",
    "total": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "THBS",
    "total": 2
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xRakin90nVz)